# Android opening app link using Intent Filter is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, deep-linking

I m using following code in my menifest to show the option to user when a relevant url is tried to be open by any source inside the mobile, but it is automatically opening web browser instead of showing my application in options.
What could be the issue?

```
<activity android:name=".VisitWebPage" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.mysite.com" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/.*" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Please show code of your activity. Especially the ``onNewIntent`` callback.
Not sure if you may do this in an Activity. Have you tried in a <Receiver>?

Comment: In activity handling it in onCreate just by this
Intent intent = getIntent();
         url = intent.getData().toString();

Comment: The difference between onCreate and onNewIntent is, that if your activity already exists (in background) it is not ``created`` again, instead you receive ``onNewIntent``. From Docs: `` In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.``

Comment: But my activity is not in background , i kill the pp to test the url, and if there is some issue in activity code then atleast app should be shown in intent options due to Menifest commands.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing your data tags to:

```
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.mysite.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="www.mysite.com" />
```

Comment: still same results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this, Its working for me.

```
<activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="mysite.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/m/showroom/mypage"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: can you paste a sample url as well, for which it is working for you?

Comment: Sorry there is no url, its in my project. we implemented this feature. you can simply create activity with this intent filter define your path prefix and host, it will work.

Comment: i am using the same but when i click on url then it is directly opened in browser.